# How to export tabulated frequencies into excel from R when using gmodels package

Tags: r, export

I was wondering if any one knew how to export tabulated frequencies from the gmodels package.  I would like to export it into separate sheets in excel.

For example, I used the code below to produce a frequency table using the gmodels package in R.

```
              CrossTable( Merge_dataset$Report_Type,Merge_dataset$name_spill, expected=F, prop.r=T, 
              prop.c=T,prop.t=T, prop.chisq=T)
```

What I want to do is to output this table with the above code and output it into excel but within a separate sheet. I have several other tables with different variables produced that I want to export in the same excel file but different sheets.

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code for `CrossTable` it builds a string to output to the console but doesn't return an object that you can use to programatically capture the table and output it to Excel. Therefore, you'll need to capture the console output and parse it. Here's an idea of how you might do that:

```r
require(magrittr)
require(openxlsx)

get_cross_table_cells <- function(x, y)
{  
  capture.output(
    CrossTable(x, y, expected = F, prop.r = T, prop.c = T,
               prop.t = T, prop.chisq = T)
                )                  %>%
  gsub("\\Q|\\E", "\t", .)         %>%    # Replace the vertical bars with tabs
  gsub("^ *", "", .)               %>%    # Remove leading whitespace
  gsub("\t( )*", "\t", .)          %>%    # Remove leading whitespace in each cell
  gsub(" *\t", "\t", .)            %>%    # Remove trailing whitespace in each cell
  extract(!grepl("---", .))        %>%    # Remove the horizontal lines
  strsplit("\t")                   ->     # Split the cells in each row
  row_list
  max_width <- max(unlist(lapply(row_list, length)))
  row_list %>%                                
  lapply(function(z) c(z, rep("", max_width - length(z)))) %>% # make rows equal size
  do.call("rbind", .) %>%                                      # collapse the list
  return
}
```

Now you need to save this data to Excel. Since you will be adding different sheets to your workbook, you want to write a function that will create a new worksheet in the existing workbook if it exists, or create a new workbook if one doesn't already exist.

You can also just insert the `get_cross_table_cells` into this function to make it easier to use. You supply it with the variables you want to cross-table, the path to your excel file, and the name of the new sheet you want to create:

```r
write_new_cross_table <- function(x, y, workbook_path, sheet_name)
{
  data <- get_cross_table_cells(x, y)

  if (file.exists(workbook_path))
  {
    cross_tables <- openxlsx::loadWorkbook(workbook_path)
  }
  else
  {
    cross_tables <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
  }

  addWorksheet(cross_tables, sheet_name)
  writeData(cross_tables, sheet_name, data, colNames = FALSE)
  saveWorkbook(cross_tables, workbook_path, overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

Now you can save your cross table as an Excel sheet. You will need to play around with the formatting of the cells, either in Excel or (better yet) via the options in the openxlsx package.

```r
write_new_cross_table(Merge_dataset$Report_Type,
                      Merge_dataset$name_spill,
                      [path to the excel file you want to use],
                      [name of the sheet you want to create])
```

Comment: Thats great. Thank you. Would it be possible to loop this function to change the variable for each loop (very similar to a SAS macro where the code is constant but only the variable changes after each iteration of the loop?). Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, @Dr.E77 . Suppose you wanted to tabulate various columns of `Merge_dataset` against `Merge_dataset$Report_Type`. If the columns you want to tabulate are, say, the second, third and fourth columns, then you can just do `for (i in 2:4) write_new_cross_table(Merge_dataset$Report_Type, Merge_dataset[[i]], {path to your excel file goes here}, names(Merge_dataset)[i])`

Comment: Hi Allan, Quick question on how you specify the workbook_path.  I keep getting errors of expected   RPAREN when I input this as the path to my file:  //ART-A_ASPCU1S/ASPCU1/DATA/R datasets.  Is there a file naming convention that I should be following in function above? Thanks!

Comment: @Dr.E77 Try `write_new_cross_table(Merge_dataset$Report_Type, Merge_dataset[[i]], " //ART-A_ASPCU1S/ASPCU1/DATA/R datasets/my_workbook.xlsx", names(Merge_dataset)[i])`

Comment: I'm afraid it"s still coming up with an error. It doesn't like the file name convention and also, I forgot to mention that it brings up an error of unmatched opening bracket here:  write_new_cross_table <- function(